# How to loop through array in batch?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I created an array like this:

```
set sources[0]="\\sources\folder1\"
set sources[1]="\\sources\folder2\"
set sources[2]="\\sources\folder3\"
set sources[3]="\\sources\folder4\"
```

Now I want to iterate through this array:

```
for %%s in (%sources%) do echo %%s
```

It doesn't work! It seems that script is not going into the loop. Why is that? How can I iterate then?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you don't know how many elements the array have (that seems is the case), you may use this method:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sources[') do echo %%s
```

Note that the elements will be processed in *alphabetical order*, that is, if you have more than 9 (or 99, etc) elements, the index must have left zero(s) in elements 1..9 (or 1..99, etc.)

Answer (score 58):

Another Alternative using defined and a loop that doesn't require delayed expansion:

```
set Arr[0]=apple
set Arr[1]=banana
set Arr[2]=cherry
set Arr[3]=donut

set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined Arr[%x%] (
    call echo %%Arr[%x%]%%
    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
```

Be sure you use "call echo" as echo won't work unless you have delayedexpansion and use ! instead of %%

Comment: I like this way. Its bit simpler

Comment: Whoever designed loops syntax in batch files was... a funny guy.

Answer (score 31):

If you don't need environment variables, do:

```
for %%s in ("\\sources\folder1\" "\\sources\folder2\" "\\sources\folder3\" "\\sources\folder4\") do echo %%s
```

Comment: This is definitely not helpful :/ I asked how to iterate through array, and you gave an answer: "just don't use the array!"

Comment: I only gave you this suggestion because sometimes I reconsider my program architecture depending on possible solutions. Imagine you had create array just to be able to iterate through items, then iterating without previous array would turn that array unneeded!

Comment: notice that space between `in` and `(`  is important. This wont work: `in("\\sources...)`  but if you write with space `in ("\\sources...)` would work

Answer (score 18):

This is one way:

```
@echo off
set sources[0]="\\sources\folder1\"
set sources[1]="\\sources\folder2\"
set sources[2]="\\sources\folder3\"
set sources[3]="\\sources\folder4\"

for /L %%a in (0,1,3) do call echo %%sources[%%a]%%
```

Comment: @LS_dev  Oh ye of little faith.  Try it. :)

Comment: You're right, my apologies! As an aside, it would be nice to have a dynamic iteration regardless of array length.

Comment: note that the `for /L` loop needs (0,1,<last_element_id>), in this case last_element_id is 3

Answer (score 5):

i use like this, what is important is that the variable is only 1 length, like %%a, and not like %%repo:

```
for %%r in ("https://github.com/patrikx3/gitlist" "https://github.com/patrikx3/gitter" "https://github.com/patrikx3/corifeus" "https://github.com/patrikx3/corifeus-builder" "https://github.com/patrikx3/gitlist-workspace" "https://github.com/patrikx3/onenote" "https://github.com/patrikx3/resume-web") do (
   echo %%r
   git clone --bare %%r
)
```

Answer (score 5):

**For posterity**: I just wanted to propose a slight modification on @dss otherwise great answer.

In the current structure the way that the DEFINED check is done causes unexpected output when you assign the value from Arr to a temporary variable inside the loop:

Example:

```
@echo off
set Arr[0]=apple
set Arr[1]=banana
set Arr[2]=cherry
set Arr[3]=donut

set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if defined Arr[%x%] (
    call set VAL=%%Arr[%x%]%%
    echo %VAL%
    REM do stuff with VAL
    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
```

This actually produces the following **incorrect** output

```
donut
apple
banana
cherry
```

The last element is printed first.
To fix this it is simpler to invert the DEFINED check to have it jump over the loop when we're done with the array instead of executing it. Like so:

```
@echo off
set Arr[0]=apple
set Arr[1]=banana
set Arr[2]=cherry
set Arr[3]=donut

set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if not defined Arr[%x%] goto :endLoop
call set VAL=echo %%Arr[%x%]%%
echo %VAL%
REM do your stuff VAL
SET /a "x+=1"
GOTO :SymLoop

:endLoop
echo "Done"
```

This regardless of what you do inside the SymLoop always produces the desired **correct** output of

```
apple
banana
cherry
donut
"Done"
```

Comment: The problem in your first example is simply the `echo %var%` change it to `call echo %%var%%` and it works as expected. Or even better, use delayed expansion

Comment: @jeb This is the crux of the issue, the code inside the loop doesn't behave as you would expect it in a normal bat script. You need to call things differently. This will be a maintenance pain in the long term.. better just make sure it works as users expect.

Comment: It behaves exactly as expected in a batch script! It's important to know, [how batch works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115), than to circumvent constructs you don't understand. And you couldn't circumvent all parenthesis blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In batch scripting, accessing an array (simulated using indexed variable names) dynamically requires a different approach due to the way delayed expansion works. You need to use a two-step variable expansion process to construct the variable name properly and then retrieve its value.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Initialize the left margin and top margin
set "left_margin=0"
set "top_margin=0"
set "max_top_margin=4"  rem Adjust this based on the size of your 'map'

rem Define variables to store each line (Consider this as a part of your 'map')
set "line[1]=:::::::::::::::::::::::::"
set "line[2]=:                       :"
set "line[3]=:  Underground book     :"
set "line[4]=:         club          :"
set "line[5]=:                       :"
set "line[6]=:                       :"
set "line[7]=:::::::::::::::::::::::::"
set "line[8]=0000"

:main
cls

rem Display content with adjusted left margin
for /l %%i in (1,1,8) do (
    set /a "line_num=%%i + top_margin"
    call :getLine !line_num!
    set "line=!line_value:~%substring_margin%!"
    set "spaces="
    for /l %%j in (1,1,!left_margin!) do (
        set "spaces=!spaces! "
    )
    echo !spaces!!line!
)

echo Z=zoom in, X=zoom out, WASD=move, Q=quit

set /p userInput=Enter a command:
if "%userInput%"=="D" (
    set /a "substring_margin-=12"  rem Decreasing reading starting position margin to move content right only when there are no spaces
    if !substring_margin! lss 0 (
        set "substring_margin=0"    
    )
    if !substring_margin! equ 0 (
        set /a "left_margin+=12"  rem Decrease left margin to move content right
        if !left_margin! lss 0 (
            set "left_margin=0"
        )
    ) 
    goto main
) else if "%userInput%"=="A" (
    if !left_margin! equ 0 (
        set /a "substring_margin+=12"  rem Increasing reading starting position margin to move content left only when there are no spaces   
    )    
    set /a "left_margin-=12"  rem Decrease left margin to move content left
    if !left_margin! lss 0 (
        set "left_margin=0"
    )
    goto main
) else if "%userInput%"=="Z" (
    rem Implement zoom in logic here
    goto main
) else if "%userInput%"=="W" (
    rem Implement move up logic here
    set /a "top_margin-=1"
    if !top_margin! lss 0 (
        set "top_margin=0"
    )
    goto main
) else if "%userInput%"=="S" (
    rem Implement move down logic here
    set /a "top_margin+=1"
    if !top_margin! gtr !max_top_margin! (
        set "top_margin=!max_top_margin!"
    )
    goto main
) else if "%userInput%"=="Q" (
    echo Exiting the program.
    pause
    exit /b
) else (
    goto main
)

:getLine
set "line_value=!line[%1]!"
goto :EOF

endlocal
```