# BATch file: Looping in an array, how to use a string from the array?

Tags: arrays, loops, batch-file

My task is to create a script to copy dated sub folders from within folders to another location.  The base folders are named 16 hex characters, each has a folder for the year, inside a folder for the month, and inside that a folder for a date, which contains binary (dump) files I need to copy out.  There are about 50 folders with around 5 days across two months that I care about (for now), so I want to capture something like the following:
C:\DUMPS\2401010153783FB6\2016\09\29*.*

Rather than doing a ton of copypaste script or manually trying to get all the folders I want (human error prone), I thought I should be able to create a BAT file to loop through an array of folder names and get at the files I care about.  I found a very helpful piece in the answer from user DSS at the following:
[How to loop through array in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462169/how-to-loop-through-array-in-batch)

My problem is that his example shows how to use CALL ECHO instead of just ECHO, but I want to use the string value as part of a folder name, not just print to the console.  Here's the work-in-progress code I've developed:

```
SET COPYPATH=C:\Dumps
SET DESTPATH=D:\NewDumps
SET FOLDERNAME[0]=2401010153783FB6
SET FOLDERNAME[1]=2401010753BBBBCE
SET "X=1" # array start from index 1

:Looping
IF DEFINED FOLDERNAME[%X%] (
    CALL ECHO %%FOLDERNAME[%X%]%% REM Works great, I see the value of FOLDERNAME[0] on console.
    SET TEMPVAR= CALL ECHO %%FOLDERNAME[%X%]%% REM No good! Result is CALL ECHO.
    SET TEMPVAR= CALL %%FOLDERNAME[%X%]%% REM No good! Result is CALL X.
    SET TEMPVAR= %FOLDERNAME[%X%]% REM No good! Result is literal FOLDERNAME[0]; I want the value of FOLDERNAME[0].
    IF EXIST %TEMPVAR%\2016\09\28 (
        COPY %TEMPVAR%\2016\09\28 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME[%X%]%%\2016\09\28
    )
    IF EXIST %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\29 (
        COPY %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\29 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\29
    )
    IF EXIST %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\30 (
        COPY %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\30 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\09\30
    )
    IF EXIST %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\01 (
        COPY %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\01 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\01
    )
    IF EXIST %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\02 (
        COPY %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\02 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\2016\10\02
    )
    SET /A "X+=1"
    GOTO :Looping
)
```

I would be fine with using a temporary variable for either path, or I could use the concatenated %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME% syntax (which worked when I set this up for a one-off test, but now I want to loop it 50 times).  Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET "COPYPATH=C:\Dumps"
SET "DESTPATH=D:\NewDumps"
SET "FOLDERNAME[0]=2401010153783FB6"
SET "FOLDERNAME[1]=2401010753BBBBCE"
rem set start to first item index, stop to last 
SET/a start=0, stop=1 


SET "DAYS=2016\09\28,2016\09\30,2016\10\01"


for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%stop%) do (
  echo !FOLDERNAME[%%i]!
  set "TEMPVAR=%COPYPATH%\!FOLDERNAME[%%i]!"
  set "DESTVAR=%DESTPATH%\!FOLDERNAME[%%i]!"
  for %%d in (%DAYS%) do (
    rem if it works, remove echo from line below
    IF EXIST "!TEMPVAR!\%%d" echo COPY "!TEMPVAR!\%%d" "!DESTPATH!\%%d"
  )

)

exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
for /L %%a in (0,1,1) do (
 for %%b in (2016) do (
  for %%c in ("09 28" "09 29" "09 30" "10 01" "10 02") do (
   call :sub %%a %%b %%~c
  )
 )
)
...whatever, etc...
goto :eof

:sub
call set "foldername=%%foldername[%1]%%"
IF EXIST %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\%2\%3\%4 (
 echo   COPY %COPYPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\%2\%3\%4 %DESTPATH%\%FOLDERNAME%\%2\%3\%4
)
goto :eof
```

where the `echo` is there to show you what is proposed, delete that `echo` keyword to execute.

Note that you offer no explanation of why you switch from `tempname`  to `copypath\foldername` in your code, so I've assumed it's incomplete substitution.

Comment: Your method involves a nested loop, which adds complexity which is a concern when someone else tries to modify/use my script a year later. But I do like that it eliminates the copy-pasted folder name code. I made my script work with J Baoby's suggestion, but I will consider doing it your way as an alternate. Your assumption is correct; perhaps I could have explained better, but I wanted to 'show my work', since the folder naming was effectively the thing that was stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose all your:

```
SET TEMPVAR=....
```

were attempts to save the result of a command into a variable
Well I have to dissapoint you on that ... there is no possibility (yet) to assign directly the result of a command to a veriable in batch ( sorry ). Indirect ways do exist: `for /f`-loops, use of temporary file, ... but they could make your code more complex
The command you are looking for is

```
call set tempvar=%%foldername[%x%]%%
```

The `call` is used to execute the commands you gave him as parameter inside a batch-file. 
So the command will look like (suppose `x=0`) `set tempvar=%foldername[0]%` and the call will just execute that (if `x=0` off course...).

Good luck!

PS: consider [@Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938759/7170434) to improve your batch script and [@elzooilogico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938889/7170434) if you'd consider to use delayed epansion.

Comment: FYI, read this [Macros with parameters appended](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518). And, I don't see nothing ugly in `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"` nor  `for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server" /V "InstalledInstances" /se @') do set "sqlInstance=%%A"` nor `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%F in ('tasklist /V /NH /FI "imagename eq chrome.exe"') do ( ...` etc etc etc. It's powerful, useful, nice and YES, complex!

Comment: maybe the term "ugly" is not the right choice but it would make his code complexer than if delayed expansion or `call` were used. Macros with parameters appended are another way to insert the result in a variable indeed.

Comment: Complexer... I like that word, not as much the concept.  I am a fan of simplicity; any complexity I can eliminate makes it easier for others to support later.  I liked the simple loop I found in the example I drew from, but I'm open to complexer when simpler doesn't work.

You are correct about my incomplete substitution; I wanted to use my code-paste to identify some of what I was in the process of trying out (and had seen not work as intended!)

Your "CALL SET TEMPVAR=" syntax is exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thanks much!

Comment: It's my pleasure! If you have the time (and if you plan to expand your batch skills) make sure to check [`FOR` loops](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) ([this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php) is also great) and macros (see link from comment @elzooilogico). They help a lot. Good luck :)