# .bat file for selectively deleting IE cache for three files

Tags: windows, batch-file, internet-explorer, flash, caching

thanks for helping out

I currently face some issues while working on a .bat file that deletes the Internet Explorer 11 cache specifically for this three files:

- Analytics.swf
- Deal.swf
- Pricing.swf

Currently I use the code attached, but it deletes all files in the cache (OS = Windows 10):

```
@echo off

set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Intern~1\

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

set History=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

del /q /s /f "%History%"
rd /s /q "%History%"

set IETemp=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1

del /q /s /f "%IETemp%"
rd /s /q "%IETemp%"

set Cookies=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies

del /q /s /f "%Cookies%"
rd /s /q "%Cookies%"

C:\bin\regdelete.exe HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs"
```

Comment: And what's the question about your code? Do you want to search and delete the 3 files in all that folders?

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the reply. I need to find a way to only delete the three files if they exits. Nothing more, nothing less. Was trying some for loops and if statements but couldn't find so far "the solution".

Comment: You can also replace all instances of `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local` with `%LocalAppData%` and any instance of `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming` with `%AppData%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch script will loop through the 4 folders you provide and search for all three files (see [how to loop through arrays in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462169/how-to-loop-through-array-in-batch)) in all subdirectories (`dir /b /s /a:-d "%%~f"`).

If the script is fine for you remove the `echo` in front of the `del` command:

```cmd
@echo off

set "filesDel[0]=Analytics.swf"
set "filesDel[1]=Deal.swf"
set "filesDel[2]=Pricing.swf"

set "dirDel[0]=%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Intern~1"
set "dirDel[1]=%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\History"
set "dirDel[2]=%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1"
set "dirDel[3]=%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies"

rem loop over all directories defined in dirDel array
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('set dirDel[') do (
   if exist "%%~d" (
      pushd "%%~d"
      rem loop over all files defined in filedDel array
      for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('set filesDel[') do (
         rem search for file and delete it
         for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "%%~f"') do (
            echo del /f "%%~g"
         )
      )
      popd
   )
)
```

Note that I use the quotes in the `set` command like: `set "name=content"`, this allows spaces in the path name without having the quotes in the variable content itself.

---

Command reference links from [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/):

- [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- [popd](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [del](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [rem](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I ll quickly check your advice and give a feedback.